# how to not encode the whole string in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to print a text and replace all "\r\n" with "<br/>", but the output returns "&lt;br/&gt". So how to not encode the text, but not the "<br/>" part?

I could use @Html.Raw, but I don't want to do that for every text.

LocalizationAccessor:

```
public string this[string name, bool global = false] 
{ 
    get
    {
        ILocalizationValue result = default;

        if (global) 
        {
            result = GetAsync(null, name).Result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = GetAsync(name).Result;
        }

        return result.HtmlValue.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
    }
}
```

HtmlValue is HtmlString.Value

View:

```
@_local["ParNewSite"]
```

**Html**:
prosessen smertefri og rask.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Alle har

Comment: provide [mre], what is your input, and what is your (desired) output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend to see a string as plain text OR html encoded text. You've created a string that is partly html encoded (the '<br/>') and partly plain text. That can't work in a real reliable way. (What if you get '<br/>' as user input?).

Solution: Do all conversion in on place:

```
var html = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(plainTextMultiLineString).Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0

Comment: yes, that's what I want, but it looks like if I use @ the text is automatically encoded. If I use @Html.Raw it works as expected

Comment: Exactly. You ensure, that everything is correctly encoded and then it's safe to output it with @Html.Raw().

Comment: Btw. CSS could be an easier solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space